# Finding a function that oscillates between 0 and 1

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a function indexed by natural numbers that oscillates between 0 and 1?
I am racking my brain but can't seem to come up with one.

Comment: Adapt $(-1)^n$...

Comment: What do you mean by “indexed by natural numbers”?

Comment: A function with domain $\mathbb{N}$ is called a sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?: $f:\mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}$

$$f(n) = \frac{1}{2} (1 + (-1)^n)$$

We have $(-1)^n = 1$ for all even $n$, and $(-1)^m = -1$ for all odd $m$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x$ even set $f(x)=1$ and for $x$ odd set $f(x)=0$. You can do this with division modulo $2$ as well.

Comment: @prets yes I put $f(x)$ instead of $x$. That would have been a much more useful comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try $f(k) = \sin^2 (a k) $  where $a$ is a real constant.

Answer (score 0):

It’s fairly easy to find functions $g$ that oscillate between $-1$ and $1$. Then you just scale and move $g$ to get the desired function $f$:
$$
f(x) = \frac12(g(x)+ 1)
$$
For example, if $g(x)= \cos(\pi x)$, then we get
$$
f(n) = \frac12(\cos(n\pi)+ 1)
$$